# DataContract Serialization gives "Index was outside the bounds of the array" exception ..C#

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer

I tried to serialize a large tree data structure in C# using dataContract serializer. I got cyclic reference exception. so I marked with  [DataContract(IsReference = true)] instead of [DataContract] against the classes wherever required. Now I get "Index was outside the bounds of the array" exception.
My code is as follows:

```
    public void Serialize(object obj, string file, Type t)
    {

        using (FileStream stream1 = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
        {
            stream1.Position = 0;
            DataContractSerializer s = new DataContractSerializer(t);

            s.WriteObject(stream1, obj);
        }


    }
```

The above code works for all other serializations . Only in the case of serializing this tree object, it does not work. I have marked with  [DataContract(IsReference = true)] against all the required classes  and [dataMember] against all the required attributes.Please help

Comment: What is the file parameter value? This param is a file path or file content?

Comment: And Why use the FileMode.Create? Is it necessary?

Comment: Parameters are :obj is the content to be serialized and file is the path, t is the typeof(obj)

Comment: FileMode.Create() is required to serialize and keep the content in the created file

Comment: So is your file already exist?

Comment: No I am creating and putting my serialized data in it.

Comment: There is no problem with file creation,I use this piece of code in many other applications for serializing.

Comment: This error is ArgumentOutOfRangeException, and this exception only thrown by FileStream constructor in your code. Just check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy(v=vs.110).aspx

So that I try to understand what is wrong with your FileStream ctor. Ok?

Comment: So what is the solution. Can u pls provide me the code

Comment: exception is thrown here  s.WriteObject(stream1, obj);

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest to mark all inherited classes with `DataContract(IsReference = true)` attribute. But you already said that you done this. So, check again your marks, and be ensure of that only inherited classes are marked. If only inherited classes are marked but you still get this error, then just check your project with `WCF Tracing`.

Tracing will show you what happens during serialization process with details.

You can find more details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: But i tried populating the tree structure( the object which i am serializing) with less elements, it worked. When populated heavily , then this error saying "Index was outside the bounds of the array" arrives. is it because the tree is heavily loaded. How can  i solve it?

Comment: Maybe data is wrong? You said that, your code works fine with less data, but getting error for heavily data. So different is the data.

I suggest again, try to WCF Tracing...

Comment: The problem is happening because the object to be serialized is too large. How do I solve it?